# Screens, resolutions, cameras, viewports chaos

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have read a few articles about resolutions, screens, viewports and cameras on the mobile phone, but I am much more confused now, that I were before. Could you please help me to keep up with issue and handle it, as currently I am working on mobile game, but without any success. I am using LibGDX.

---

> Regarding to answer below I changed my program (thanks for explanation Xoppa :)

***New piece of code:***

```
    @Override
    public void create () {
        orthographicCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        fillViewport = new FillViewport(960, 600, orthographicCamera);      
        orthographicCamera.position.set(orthographicCamera.viewportWidth * 0.5f, orthographicCamera.viewportHeight * 0.5f, 0);
        fillViewport.apply();
    }
```

.

```
@Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.22f, 0.22f, 0.22f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        ...
}
```

.

```
@Override
    public void resize (int width, int height) {
        fillViewport.update(960, 600);
        orthographicCamera.position.set(960 * 0.5f, 600 * 0.5f, 0);
    }
```

> But the result is the same.

***Output:***
[image]
Two small dots are my players. :(

> Even if I change the Viewport resolution, size of my players do not change. The only thing that change was visible resolution of viewport, behind it I do not see mz players. I sketeched it for better imagination (values are just for imagination).

***Physics body of my players:***

```
public Character(Vector2 startPosition) {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(startPosition);

    // Create our body in the world using our body definition
    body = Physic.gameWorld.createBody(bodyDef);

    // Create a circle shape and set its radius to 6
    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setPosition(new Vector2());
    circle.setRadius(0.39f);

    // Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = circle;
    fixtureDef.density = 1f;

    // Create our fixture and attach it to the body
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    circle.dispose();
}
```

> Even if I change the radius of the circle, body will need much more energy to manipulate with and also body is not big enough. Of course I can not set the radius to value which is more than 10f as Box2D doc not recommended it.

But I do not see anything, when I run it, or created physical world objects are too small or flattened (physical world configuration and initialization is good I think; radius of circle physical objects are 0.39). Or am I missing something in the code, some statements or anything else?

But I think I have problem with correct understanding of mentioned issues.

Could you please help me with this or explain it?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to understand what a camera and viewport is and does. Perhaps this example might help:

Imagine that you're in the park and take a photo with your camera/smartphone of a tree and a bench. The bench is e.g. 3 meters wide and half a meter in height and depth. The tree might be e.g. half a meter wide and 10 meters in height. Now if you look at the photo on the screen of your camera/smartphone, then you'll see that the bench is no longer 3 meters wide, instead it is just a few millimeters wide. The actual size depends on how you've setup your camera (e.g. zoom) as well as the resolution of the photo (in pixels) and the density of the screen you're watching it on.

So practically in the example above the bench and the tree have two different sizes: the actual size in the park in the physical world and the size on the screen you're watching the photo on. Of course the tree and the bench don't actually shrink depending on the photo, they stay the same size. The size on the photo is only the size of the *projection* of the tree and the bench.

Projection is practically transforming world objects onto the screen, based on various camera settings (like zoom, position, etc.).

The park is much bigger than only the portion you've taken the photo of. When you took the photo you decided which portion of the park (the physical world) you want to project onto the photo. Let's call this the park's viewport.

Likewise you also don't have infinite storage to project the photo, you'll have to define the portion (the resolution of the photo) you want to project onto. Let's call this the photo's viewport.

The park's viewport is expressed in real world units, like meters or inches e.g. The photo's viewport is expressed in pixels (the resolution you've set it to).

When making a game you typically aren't making a photo but rendering to screen. Therefor the photo's viewport is then called the *screen viewport*. And when making a game your park might not even exist, your game world is virtual. Therefor the park's viewport is then called the *virtual viewport*.

On a small side-note: pixels are always integers, therefor *screenviewport* is always expressed in `int`. World units like meters or inches can be fractional, therefor *virtualviewport* is always expressed in `float`.

The `Camera` class of libgdx does exactly what is described above, it performs the the projection of your virtual world onto the screen. However, in practice that comes with some problems. E.g. not every screen has the same aspect ratio. Therefor you need to define how you want to cope with differences in aspect ratio. E.g. add black bars, expand the virtual world or stretch it, etc.

The `Viewport` class of libgdx solves that problem by implementation [various strategies](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) you can choose from on how to define your virtualviewport and screenviewport. To do this it encapsulates (and manages) a camera for you.

In your code you've given it a `OrthographicCamera` in the constructor to manage, which is typically used for 2D games. The *virtualviewport* you've set the `OrthographicCamera` to in the constructor is overwritten though. Because you've chosen to use a `ScreenViewport`. This is an implementation that makes the *virtualviewport* (the portion of the park) the same as the *screenviewport* (the portion of the screen).

It is very unlikely that you want to use that viewport implementation. Instead you probably want to use e.g. a `FillViewport`:

```
public void create () {
        viewport = new FillViewport(50f, 50f);
}
```

This creates a *virtualviewport* that grows if needed to maintain aspect ratio. The 50 by 50 is in world units, e.g. meters or inches.

Now we need to tell the viewport which *screenviewport* to use. This depends on the size of the screen of the device and is therefor best set in the `resize` method.

```
public void resize (int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

All other code of these methods of you can be removed, you dont need them. You dont need to update the camera in your render method. You can just use the viewport as you normally would. And if you need access to the camera directly (but not to modify it, only to read e.g. its projection matrix), then you can use:

```
viewport.getCamera()
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask you, isn't that depends on orthographic/perspective projection? Because, in case of perspective projection we see, as you wrote, bench of 10 meters just few millimeter wide on the photo. But in case of orthographic projection everything seems the same size. Orthographic projection does not have depth. And I am using orthographic projection in my situation.
So when using orthographic projection plus FillViewport, does it means, that variable 50f will be world size and when I create physicall object with radius of 0.39 it will be very small? Am I right?

Comment: Orthographic projection just doesn't include perspective. So with ortographic the *projection of* the bench on the photo wouldnt get smaller when the distance between the bench and the camera increases. However, for 2D that doesnt matter. You just specify the size of your *virtual viewport* and your *screen viewport*. If you specify 50x50 for the virtual viewport then that radius will be 0.39/50=~0.8% of the visible viewport. The projection then would be e.g. 0.39/50*720=~6 pixels height on a 720 pixels height screen.